# Having insert statement and procedure after FORALL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, forall

How can I have one insert statement and call procedure after FORALL in plsql?

I have the following in procedure

```
FORALL indx IN p_product.FIRST .. p_product.LAST
        INSERT INTO   my_table
              VALUES   (p_product(indx),p_product_desc(indx),p_msg);
```

After the insert I would like to call another procedure which inserts values into another table.

```
remove_dup_products(p_product(indx));
```

When I had tried to call the above procedure after insert statement, I am getting error

```
INDX must be declared
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [FORALL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/forall_statement.htm#LNPLS01321) statement is just that; a statement; you can only do one thing in it. You have to loop through your type again.

```
forall indx in p_product.first .. p_product.last
   insert into my_table
   values (p_product(indx), p_product_desc(indx), p_msg);

for indx in p_product.first .. p_product.last loop
   remove_dup_products(p_product(indx));
end loop;
```

It's worth nothing that you're not doing two DML statements; you're doing one and calling a procedure. You cannot therefore use FORALL twice, you have to use a regular for loop.

If you're *only* doing DML in the second procedure you could pass in the entire collection and then use FORALL then. You would need to declare a global variable:

```
create or replace package something is

   type t__product is table of product.product%type;
   t_product t__product;

   ...
```

and then you could reuse this everywhere

```
create or replace package body something is

procedure current_proc is

begin

   forall indx in p_product.first .. p_product.last
      insert into my_table
      values (p_product(indx), p_product_desc(indx), p_msg);

   remove_dup_products(p_product);

end current_proc;

-------------------------------------------------------------

procedure remove_dup_products (p_product in t_product) is

begin

    forall in p_product.first .. p_product.last
       delete ...
```

Comment: Ben by doing this does this cause a plsql to sql switch?

Comment: It depends what you're doing in your procedure @Polppan; if you can move the stuff that's happening into that procedure into an INSERT statement in what you're executing then it would be better.

Comment: Ben in `remove_dup_products` procedure I am deleting `product_id` from three tables. So it is not insert statements in procedure.

Comment: As long as it's DML then it's the same thing @Polppan. I've updated my answer with another option though.

Comment: @Polppan The context switching will be taking place regardless of what you are using, `FORALL` statement or regular `FOR LOOP` statement, the question is how often? In case of `FORALL` statement, as it sends `DML` statements to SQL engine in batches it will occur once whereas `FOR LOOP` statement, as it sends `DML` statement to the SQL engine one at a time, will cause context switching  with each iteration.

Comment: @Ben My second stored procedure is not part of a package. So I would like to create a ROWTYPE so that I can refer more than one column from  `my_table` table. I have tried to create a type as `CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE t_product IS TABLE OF my_table%ROWTYPE`. However I am getting compilation errors. What is the best approach if I would want to refer more than one column in second procedure so that I can have those columns in delete where condition. Thanks

Comment: You would need to explicitly create the columns in your type though; @Polppan, that's why you're getting the error. I don't think you can bulk collect into a rowtype in 10g. To reference more than than one column you could pass in multiple collections; or if your procedure is only 3 deletes you could simple reimplement those deletes in your current package and leaves notes everywhere.